# Async MVC5 controller and async EF DataContext

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm reading many articles and seen example of mvc project, but find the answer on my question could not, help me please.

**Question:**
I'm have simple example of async mvc5 application, but i'm not understand what happens underline, which version is right and why? Big thanks.

**Example**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<JsonResult> NamesAsync()
    {
        var result = await new TestService().GetNamesAsync();
        return Json(result,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public async Task<JsonResult> Names()
    {
        var result = await new TestService().GetName();
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

}

public sealed class TestService
{
    public async Task<List<string>> GetNamesAsync()
    {
        return await new DataLayer().GetNamesAsync();
    }

    public Task<List<string>> GetName()
    {
        return Task<List<string>>.Factory.StartNew(() => new DataLayer().GetNames());
    }
}


public sealed class DataLayer
{
    public async Task<List<string>> GetNamesAsync()
    {
        using (var context = new TestContext())
        {
            return await context.Names.Select(x => x.NameText).ToListAsync();
        }
    }

    public List<string> GetNames()
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<List<string>>();

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            using (var context = new TestContext())
            {
                var names = context.Names.Select(x => x.NameText).ToList();
                tcs.SetResult(names);
            }
        });

        Task.WhenAll(tcs.Task);

        return tcs.Task.Result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One rule for asynchronous code is "don't let your code lie." There are some operations (particularly I/O) that are inherently asynchronous, and they should expose asynchronous APIs.

Databases are I/O-bound, so they fall into that naturally-asynchronous category:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<JsonResult> NamesAsync()
    {
        var result = await new TestService().GetNamesAsync();
        return Json(result,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}

public sealed class TestService
{
    public async Task<List<string>> GetNamesAsync()
    {
        return await new DataLayer().GetNamesAsync();
    }
}

public sealed class DataLayer
{
    public async Task<List<string>> GetNamesAsync()
    {
        using (var context = new TestContext())
        {
            return await context.Names.Select(x => x.NameText).ToListAsync();
        }
    }
}
```